# Thread safe FIFO / Queue (Multiple producers, one consumer)

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, fifo

As the title says, I'm trying to write a queue that can be written to by multiple threads and read by a single one. As an added difficulty, I need the queue inputs to remain ordered (First In, First Out). This is where I'm lost. Mutexes aren't necessarily waken up in the order that they were locked, so I don't know what I could use in order to achieve what I want? Here is a simple program illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>

using std::ofstream;

ofstream myFile("result.txt");
Queue<int> myQueue;

DWORD WINAPI WritingThread(LPVOID lpParam);
DWORD WINAPI LockingThread(LPVOID lpParam);

int main()
{
    // This thread will block myQueue for 3 seconds
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, LockingThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    // During the locked period, I ask myQueue to push numbers from 0 to 49
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, WritingThread, (LPVOID)new int(i), 0, NULL);

    // If the mutex could wake up in order, myQueue would pop up the numbers in order, but it doesn't.
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        myFile << myQueue.pop() << ",";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD WINAPI LockingThread( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    myQueue.lockQueueFor3Seconds();
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI WritingThread( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    myQueue.push(*(int*)lpParam);
    return 0;
}
```

The code for the class Queue was taken [there, see the bottom of the article for full code.](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/) All I did was adding the method "lockQueueFor3Seconds" for testing purpose. The method is defined as such:

```
void lockQueueFor3Seconds()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
    Sleep(3000);
}
```

The output of that test looks like this:

```
1,43,39,46,36,44,49,40,35,42,32,31,28,41,27,38,24,23,20,34,19,16,15,12,37,11,7,8,3,33,30,0,45,4,26,18,48,21,47,22,25,17,14,10,6,29,9,2,13,5
```

As you can see, clearly not ordered. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I modified the queue so that it attributes a number to each push call representing their order, when the mutex gets unlocked, queue checks to make sure that it's the correct method's turn before adding an element, otherwise it goes back to waiting. Not sure if I implemented this properly, but it seems to work! The complete code can be found [there](https://github.com/5tapl3r/Concurrent_queue_FIFO/blob/master/threadsafe_queue.cpp).

Comment: They are ordered, in the order you put them onto the queue. You're wrong in assuming that the threads you start get run-time in the order you create them. Try putting a sleep between each thread create.

Comment: Side Notes: Why no std::thread? Avoid `new`, you have a memory leak.

Comment: Pass the priority as an argument to the thread and use that in your resulting priority-queue

Comment: @DieterLücking No particular reason, it's just the first thing that came to my mind when I made this code. About the "new", I'm aware I should be careful with it but in this scenario the program instantly closes when the task is over so I doubt the memory leak could really bother me...

Comment: @kfsone Obviously they are ordered in the order I put them onto the queue, I'm asking how to put them onto the queue in the correct order (from 0 to 50). Putting a Sleep between each thread create would completely ruins my test, as in real life I don't have that kind of control over when the writing is done...

Comment: @DieterLücking In this test I could do that, but I'm talking about a real world scenario where you have many threads writing at once, how do you know the priority?

Comment: @MyUsername112358 There is your question, solve it!

Comment: @DieterLücking In my real life application, it's impossible. I'm dealing with injected code of a third party application, I've literally no way of knowing the priority of elements to add. All I can do is find a way that the mutex (or other locking mechanism) get waken up at the right time. You are just avoiding answering my question. It's okay if you don't know how, let someone else who does answer instead of giving me advices that I don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never work to assign the thread the value to add and expect them to be added in order because you can't force the order the threads execute in.

Instead, have each thread add the next number (whatever it may be) when it runs.  Like this:

```
std::atomic_int counter;

DWORD WINAPI WritingThread( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    myQueue.push( counter++ );
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  It isn't enough that the increment is atomic.  The increment AND the push to the queue needs to be a single atomic operation.  That means exposing the lock variable outside of the class (it's already public).

```
std::atomic_int counter;

DWORD WINAPI WritingThread( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(myQueue.m_mutex);
    myQueue.push( counter++ );
    return 0;
}
```

That will work if your `mutex` implementation lets the same thread call it multiple times.  Otherwise, you can do something similar to this:

```
void pushAndIncrement(T& item)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
    queue_.push(item);
            ++item;
    mlock.unlock();
    cond_.notify_one();
}
```

I think your solution (which you say is working) still has a race condition.  If there is a context switch after it increments the letter value, but before it increments the `counter` value inside of `push`, it will add the letter in the wrong order.  It's such a small window, it might be unlikely to happen, but if you put the counter increment inside of the same lock as the push, it will be perfect, everytime.

Comment: I don't think so.  I think the `push` method locks automagically.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code onto mine and it still returns the numbers disordered, I've no idea why... have you tested it on your side?

Comment: I hadn't before, but after you said that, I created a new project, added your code, the Queue.h code, and ran it.  The `results.txt` file has all the numbers, in order, from 0 to 49.

Maybe try do a complete rebuild?  Just to make sure that you're running the code with the changes.  The atomic should do the trick.

Comment: I cleaned the project then rebuilt the whole solution, tried on debug mode and release mode, still not working. Any idea why I would not get the same results as you do?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't get the same result.  I put the code I used into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dwcullop/83ec8f7b468f3b4fd8fa) for you.  Maybe try it and if it works, compare to what you used and see if there's a difference.

Comment: Still the same problem even though I copied your whole code from scratch (new project too)... What are you compiling with? I'm using microsoft visual studio 2013 with default options...

Comment: I'm using VS2015.  I've tried 32-bit Debug and Release and 64-bit Debug and Release and they all produce the correct result.  I created [another Gist](https://gist.github.com/dwcullop/9b84d4f0abb43ddc0fe7) that uses the individual files that I am using (instead of putting it all in one).

I hope that helps.  I'm not sure what you're doing differently.

Comment: Hey! I solved my problem (I think), you can see what I did in my edit. I don't see how your code could work, as even though the data is atomic, it still get pushed in random order given that mutexes get released in a random order too. Still, your answer is mostly responsible for me finding a solution, so if you want to edit it with the new information I would be very happy to accept it!